# Using @Before method in JUnit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

I saw this question: [Repeating code in JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359060/repeating-code-in-junit-tests) earlier today. How do you write this code when you are starting? You see that there is a method `addDrivingRecord(...)`. This method does not exist when you first start writing so do you make that test, ensure that it works, then proceed with `setUp()` method, or do you instead wait until you have written the `addDrivingRecord(...)` method and then refactor it to the `@Before`?  I will explain further if needed.

Comment: So your question is "should I use addDrivingRecord in the test method / implement addDrivingRecord / ensure it works / refactor" or should I refactor addDrivingRecord first and then implement it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your question is about methodology you could retag it as tdd (or test-driven-development).

Comment: If you write a new test class, why write something when you know you are going to refactor anyways? I am not sure if I understand your question right, but whether writing a new test or just refactoring an old one, the test results should be the same. So do all the refactoring, then the testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood well your asking if you should:

1. use addDrivingRecord in the test method
2. ensure it goes green (it works)
3. refactor addDrivingRecord to @Before

or

1. use addDrivingRecord in the test method
2. refactor addDrivingRecord to @Before
3. ensure it goes green (it works)

If it's your question I should go for the first option: first use method, then implement and go green, then refactor your test.

Because two reasons:

1. You should test/implement one thing at a time, so you will write *one* test method. Then you will make it green. Only then you should write another method and realize that code can be refactored in a @Before
2. A good practice is write test methods and only when you realize there are common things move them to @Before. That way you don't enforce innecesary things in initialization. Moreover, if you find that another test needs a very different @Before method it probably belongs to another test class.