# copy .aspx webform error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to copy my .aspx file and paste it with all its content,
but I run into an error.

this is what I did :
1. Copy - Paste.
2. rename the new aspx file in the solution explorer.
3. rename the Inherits in the aspx file  (the "code behind" there was already changed automatically for some reason..)

I run into an error :  "Type WebApplication21.Home" already defines a member called Page_Load with the same parameter types

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your relevant code behind code, and the header of your aspx page

Comment: public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

This is what I have now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code behind (`.aspx.cs`) file, you need to ensure the class name has also changed.

And in the `.aspx` page, in the `@ Page` directive make sure the correct class name is used.

On another note: [Why is “copy and paste” of code dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2490884/1583)

Comment: public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: @user1054375 - Exactly my point. You already _have_ a `Home` class. You need to rename this one to the name of the file to avoid duplicates.

Comment: But the name of the file is "Home"..
The aspx file that I copied from is "Webform1", and the new one is "Home"

Comment: @user1054375 - And the name of the class on `Webform1`?