# How to share information with a new process (besides the command-line arguments)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, process

I'm starting a new process with:

```
process.Start();
```

I know I can pass strings to it using:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = ...
```

But I want to share more than just a couple of simple strings – a byte array etc. How do I do that?

EDIT: This is going to be installed as a ClickOnce application, so I don't really know where it will be installed in the file system, and I want to keep it as simple as possible so no files will remain after an uninstall. So where do I put this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is small you can just **base64** encode it. Other options consist of saving data to the **file** or using **[named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks. Base64 is probably the closest to what I'm looking for. Unless arguments of other types (besides strings) can be passed to a process in some way that nobody here has found.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) - they allow you to share data between processes.

Alternatives are regular files, the registry, communicating over [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) and more.

Comment: @JakubKonecki - Another on for [Why is “copy and paste” of code dangerous?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2490884/1583) ;)

Comment: Applies to SO comments as well... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Anonymous Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx).

> Anonymous pipes offer less functionality than named pipes, but also
>   require less overhead. You can use anonymous pipes to make
>   interprocess communication on a local computer easier. You cannot use
>   anonymous pipes for communication over a network.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp file, write all required data into it and send result file name as a command line argument.
When the second application run it will read the content of file and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

if you can encode the byte array properly (e.g. base64), you can redirect stdin of the target process and stream it through that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx