# Approach to be followed for deploying the application

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, struts, web-deployment

We have developed a web based application in java(STRUTS 2.0). Now we want to deploy the application. The client is having one pre UAT environment ,UAT environment and a production environment.

Now when we are deploying for pre-UAT we have created the copy of our project and renamed it to pre-UAT. Similarly we are planning for UAT environment and one we already have for development. So in all we will be having 3 copies of our code.

I want to ask is this approach correct or what is the standard approach followed. This is not our final release as we are first releasing a version and then we will be working on other modules.

So please can anyone guide me for approach to follow for creating this 3 different environments.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you refer to by "we will be having 3 copies of our code". If you are implying that you actually copied the code-base around multiple times, please stop reading and refer to this:

[Why is "copy and paste" of code dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490884/why-is-copy-and-paste-of-code-dangerous)

And once you finish reading, do some research about source control and how to use branching/tagging for concurrent development.

---

If you were referring to multi-environment *deployment*:

Assuming your application is designed correctly (and I'm treading very carefully here), one WAR file (you were mentioning you're using Tomcat, so I am concluding that your application is packaged as a WAR) should be sufficient. The application code should be environment-independent and should read its environment-specific configuration from external resources, such as a database, configuration files or JNDI.

If your application code is environment-independent, then all you need to do is simply deploy the WAR file to each of the environments (the same WAR file), plus the environment-specific set of external artifacts (such as configuration files).

Comment: Creating a war and deploying on different environment is not a problem.

Comment: OK, that doesn't provide much more information about what is the challenge that you're trying to resolve. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Consider it as,Now we have developed a module and we have deployed it on the pre-UAT environment. The tester may take a week or n days to test the module. So by that time we are going to start development of new module ar some enhancement in the code. The preUAT tester reports to us some bugs. As we have already started developing on new screens we want to have  the specific version which we sent for pre-UAT. So we have copied the project which we sent for pre-UAT. so we will fix the issues found by tester and redeploy. So in this case the new development is not mixed with the earlier version.

Comment: In other words, you're looking for strategies concerning source control management and branching. Which source control manager (SCM) are you using?

Comment: Reproduce and fix preUAT bug on latest code base. Another approach: create tags in version control for each released artifact, then developers can return to that tag, create new branch from it, commit bugfixes, then merge or cherry-pick bugfixes into trunk (master branch).