# Variable 'menu' might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I tried to make a menu that uses `switch` and `do while`, but it returns:

> variable 'menu' might not have been initialized

```
} while (menu != 5);
```

Can anybody help me please? This is my goal:

[image: pic]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  class HW {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entry = new Scanner(System.in);
    int A, B, X, menu; // there
    do {
      System.out.println("Main Menu");
      System.out.println("1.  Plus");
      System.out.println("2.  Minus");
      System.out.println("3.  Multiply");
      System.out.println("4.  Division");
      System.out.println("5.  Exit");
      System.out.println("Option :");
      X = entry.nextInt();
      switch (X) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("Var A : ");
          A = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Var B : ");
          B = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Result : " + (A + B));
          if (A > B)
            System.out.println(A + ">" + B);
          else if (A == B)
            System.out.println(A + "=" + B);
          else if (A < B)
            System.out.println(A + "<" + B);
          System.out.println("*press any key back to menu*");
          menu = entry.nextInt(); // there
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("Var A : ");
          A = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Var B : ");
          B = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Result : " + (A - B));
          if (A > B)
            System.out.println(A + ">" + B);
          else if (A == B)
            System.out.println(A + "=" + B);
          else if (A < B)
            System.out.println(A + "<" + B);
          System.out.println("*press any key back to menu*");
          menu = entry.nextInt(); //there
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("Var A : ");
          A = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Var B : ");
          B = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Result : " + (A * B));
          if (A > B)
            System.out.println(A + ">" + B);
          else if (A == B)
            System.out.println(A + "=" + B);
          else if (A < B)
            System.out.println(A + "<" + B);
          System.out.println("*press any key back to menu*");
          menu = entry.nextInt(); //there
          break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println("Var A : ");
          A = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Var B : ");
          B = entry.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Result : " + (A / B));
          if (A > B)
            System.out.println(A + ">" + B);
          else if (A == B)
            System.out.println(A + "=" + B);
          else if (A < B)
            System.out.println(A + "<" + B);
          System.out.println("*press any key back to menu*");
          menu = entry.nextInt(); //there
          break;
        case 5:
          break;
      }
    } while (menu != 5); //here it say not initialized.
    System.out.println(" ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please refactor the code to use a helper method for executing the calculation. Currently the code blocks within each `case` are duplicate except to the single character which corresponds to the performed operation (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). Some motivation in [Why is “copy and paste” of code dangerous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490884/why-is-copy-and-paste-of-code-dangerous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to make the error go away, initialize the `menu` variable:

```
int A;
int B;
int X;
int menu = -1; // Initialize menu to -1
```

Your switch statement needs to be sure to handle all possible cases, though. You can ensure it does by adding a default case.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `default` statement after your last `case`. This is because if none of the cases are true, it still needs a "back-up plan". It's the counter part for the `else` statement.

Add this after `case: 5`:

```
default:
    menu = desiredNumberHere;
    break;
```

Comment: thanks. but now it say : (error cannot find symbols). the same place, }while(menu != 5);

Answer (score 1):

```
while (menu != 5);
```

See, what if no cases satisfied?
 That is why you need an initialization there.

Either you need to initialize or provide a `default` case in switch.

So, that's why there is always guaranteed to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

You have only declared the variables `int A, B, X, menu`; but not initialized these. So, what you have to do is put any value according to your requirement to `manu` variable.